argocd faild connection with public github repo
i try to deployed argoCD on minikube and when i try to connect argo with public gitub repo it tells me faild
and rty to create an app on argo and this is the error:
"Unable to create application: application spec for gp-laravel-app is invalid: InvalidSpecError: repository not accessible: repositories not accessible: &Repository{Repo: "https://github.com/zsnakeee/museum.git", Type: "", Name: "", Project: ""}: repo client error while testing repository: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: Get "https://github.com/zsnakeee/museum.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack": dial tcp: lookup github.com on 10.96.0.10:53: server misbehaving"
i dont know what should i do

Your minikube's DNS connectivity is failing. Something is wrong with the way it's set up. Try K3s / Rancher Desktop depending on your environment - hopefully, you'll get better results there.

Are you using the UI or CLI for this?

as we can see the error is about resolving github.com and this issue is not related to ArgoCD, you need to check your DNS container/Service.
for the test, you can port-forward dns service and check GitHub reservation:
kubectl -n kube-system port-forward svc/kube-dns 5353:53
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 +tcp +short github.com
